# Click on the treenode to highlight text field in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, split, treeview, richtextbox

I have a project to do the mission:

Click on the treenode then highlight the correlative field in the RichTextBox. The text in RichTextBox is separated by "|".

I am using code to find in RichTextBox but it is not the solution.

The example of my project is 7edit software like that:
http://postimg.org/image/k0u3mgb1x/

Some on can help me to do this mission, please!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add whatever code that does find in the richtextbox to the `NodeMouseClick` event handler.
If you need to add more info for the tree nodes to help find, you can use the `Tag` property.